# How are facebook updates received

Tags: ajax, facebook

When I use facebook, If someone posts a new status or a comment or whatever new content, I receive the updates on my facebook homepage without having to refresh it. How does that work ??

Answer (score 5):

Likely they use a javascript timer which periodically performs an Ajax request and updates the page in the browser when something was posted.

[wikipedia entry on Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure what they use, but i think they probally using node.js (http://nodejs.org/) which is like ajax, but not ajax. it listens to webSockets which is very cool.